# Как сгруппировать DataFrame по одному столбцу чтобы получить список значений другого столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня в DataFrame есть два столбца: `id` и `info` (кортеж).

Как я могу сгруппировать по `id` так, чтобы для каждого `id` у меня был список из кортежей этого `id`?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой (3-5 строк) воспроизводимый пример исходного DataFrame'а и то что вы хотите получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопка "править" - воспользуйтесь ей чтобы изменить вопрос. В комментариях невозможно отформатировать данные или код

Answer (score 4):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]:
   id    info
0   1  (a, a)
1   1  (a, b)
2   2  (b, a)
3   2  (b, b)
4   2  (b, c)
5   3  (c, a)
```

Решение:

```
In [51]: res = df.groupby('id')['info'].apply(list)
```

Результат:

```
In [52]: res
Out[52]:
id
1            [(a, a), (a, b)]
2    [(b, a), (b, b), (b, c)]
3                    [(c, a)]
Name: info, dtype: object
```

или так:

```
In [57]: res = df.groupby('id')['info'].apply(list).reset_index(name='info')

In [58]: res
Out[58]:
   id                      info
0   1          [(a, a), (a, b)]
1   2  [(b, a), (b, b), (b, c)]
2   3                  [(c, a)]
```

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли вопрос; когда я пробую так написать у меня ошибка: cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'dataframegroupby' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: @ЕвгенияКутузова, похоже вы пытаетесь применить `.groupby()` к результату другого `df.groupby()` - так сделать не получится. Чтобы вам помочь мне понадобится воспроизводимый пример данных, который поможет воспроизвести проблему...

Comment: К сожалению у меня сейчас несть доступа к компу:(

Comment: Попробую объяснить так

Comment: Изначально у меня есть поля Id, status и date; далее я делаю так: df ['info']=df[ ['status', 'date']].apply (tuple, axes=1) ; del df [status]; del df [date']; потом пробую то что вы написали, но он не группирует в лист почему-то, что я не так делаю?

Comment: @ЕвгенияКутузова, не могу воспроизвести вашу ошибку с моим игрушечным DF. Попробуйте привести __в вопросе__ воспроизводимый пример данных

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один вариант решения:

Исходный DF:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   id    status        date
0   1  status_1  2019-01-01
1   1  status_2  2019-01-02
2   2  status_3  2019-01-03
3   2  status_4  2019-01-04
4   2  status_5  2019-01-05
5   3  status_6  2019-01-06
```

Решение:

```
res = (df.groupby('id')
         [['status','date']]
         .apply(lambda x: tuple(x.values))
         .reset_index(name='info'))
```

Результат:

```
In [18]: res
Out[18]:
   id                                                                      info
0   1                          ([status_1, 2019-01-01], [status_2, 2019-01-02])
1   2  ([status_3, 2019-01-03], [status_4, 2019-01-04], [status_5, 2019-01-05])
2   3                                                 ([status_6, 2019-01-06],)
```